# Closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^{M}e^{-ax^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, summation

I stumbled upon this one today, and I have the suspicion I could probably solve it after a few hours of tinkering but I'm not up for that kind of labor right now. Any pointers?

$$G=\sum_{n=0}^{M}e^{-ax^{n}}$$ for some real $a>0$ and $x\in \mathbb{C}$, $|x|=1$

Comment: @OlivierOloa It's a finite sum. I don't think you are going to get a closed formula in general.

Comment: Yep I didn't see the sum was finite...

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a closed form, but one might note that if $x^b=1$, and $b\in\mathbb N$, then we have:

$$\sum_{n=0}^Me^{-ax^n}=\lfloor M/b\rfloor\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{b-1}e^{-ax^n}}_{\text{constant}}+\sum_{n=0}^{M\pmod b}e^{-ax^n}$$

Which is a tad closer to "closed form".